# Значение по умолчанию в настройках

Tags: android

Пытаюсь сделать настройки в приложении. Есть `ListPreference`, в который вывожу массив `currency_names`, которая хранит названия валют в виде "Доллар США, Российский рубль и т.д.", для значений используется другой массив, который хранит коды валют USD, RUB и т.д. Как сделать так, чтобы при открытии приложения по дефолту стояла валюта Российский рубль? Пишу `defaultValue="105"`, т.к. у массиве `currency_names` рубль под 105 индексом, но при запуске приложения валюта по умолчанию не выбрана.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Основная валюта">

        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="105"
            android:entries="@array/currency_names"
            android:entryValues="@array/currency_codes"
            android:key="main_currency"
            android:summary="Выберите основную валюту"
            android:title="Основная валюта" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Массивы

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="currency_names">
        <item>Австралийский доллар</item>
        <item>Азербайджанский манат</item>
        <item>Алжирский динар</item>
        <item>Аргентинское песо</item>
        <item>Армянский драм</item>
        <item>Арубанский флорин</item>
        <item>Афгани</item>
        <item>Багамский доллар</item>
        <item>Бальбоа</item>
        <item>Барбадосский доллар</item>
        <item>Бат</item>
        <item>Бахрейнский динар</item>
        <item>Белизский доллар</item>
        <item>Белорусский рубль</item>
        <item>Бермудский доллар</item>
        <item>Болгарский лев</item>
        <item>Боливиано</item>
        <item>Бразильский реал</item>
        <item>Брунейский доллар</item>
        <item>Бурундийский франк</item>
        <item>Вату</item>
        <item>Восточно-карибский доллар</item>
        <item>Гайанский доллар</item>
        <item>Ганский седи</item>
        <item>Гвинейский франк</item>
        <item>Гибралтарский фунт</item>
        <item>Гонконгский доллар</item>
        <item>Гривна</item>
        <item>Гуарани</item>
        <item>Гурд</item>
        <item>Даласи</item>
        <item>Датская крона</item>
        <item>Денар</item>
        <item>Дирхам ОАЭ</item>
        <item>Добра</item>
        <item>Доллар Зимбабве</item>
        <item>Доллар Намибии</item>
        <item>Доллар Островов Кайман</item>
        <item>Доллар США</item>
        <item>Доллар Соломоновых Островов</item>
        <item>Доллар Тринидада и Тобаго</item>
        <item>Доллар Фиджи</item>
        <item>Доминиканское песо</item>
        <item>Донг</item>
        <item>Евро</item>
        <item>Египетский фунт</item>
        <item>Замбийская квача</item>
        <item>Злотый</item>
        <item>Золотая кордоба</item>
        <item>Иена</item>
        <item>Индийская рупия</item>
        <item>Иорданский динар</item>
        <item>Иракский динар</item>
        <item>Иранский риал</item>
        <item>Исландская крона</item>
        <item>Йеменский риал</item>
        <item>Канадский доллар</item>
        <item>Катарский риал</item>
        <item>Кванза</item>
        <item>Квача</item>
        <item>Кенийский шиллинг</item>
        <item>Кетсаль</item>
        <item>Кина</item>
        <item>Кип</item>
        <item>Колумбийское песо</item>
        <item>Конвертируемая марка</item>
        <item>Конголезский франк</item>
        <item>Коста-риканский колон</item>
        <item>Кубинское песо</item>
        <item>Кувейтский динар</item>
        <item>Кьят</item>
        <item>Лари</item>
        <item>Лек</item>
        <item>Лемпира</item>
        <item>Леоне</item>
        <item>Либерийский доллар</item>
        <item>Ливанский фунт</item>
        <item>Ливийский динар</item>
        <item>Лилангени (Эмалангени)</item>
        <item>Лоти (Малоти)</item>
        <item>Маврикийская рупия</item>
        <item>Малагасийский ариари</item>
        <item>Малайзийский ринггит</item>
        <item>Марокканский дирхам</item>
        <item>Мексиканское песо</item>
        <item>Мозамбикский метикал</item>
        <item>Молдавский лей</item>
        <item>Найра</item>
        <item>Накфа</item>
        <item>Нгултрум</item>
        <item>Непальская рупия</item>
        <item>Нидерландский антильский гульден</item>
        <item>Новозеландский доллар</item>
        <item>Новый израильский шекель</item>
        <item>Новый соль</item>
        <item>Новый тайваньский доллар</item>
        <item>Новый туркменский манат</item>
        <item>Норвежская крона</item>
        <item>Оманский риал</item>
        <item>Паанга</item>
        <item>Пакистанская рупия</item>
        <item>Патака</item>
        <item>Пула</item>
        <item>Риель</item>
        <item>Российский рубль</item>
        <item>Румынский лей</item>
        <item>Рупия</item>
        <item>Руфия</item>
        <item>Рэнд</item>
        <item>Сальвадорский колон</item>
        <item>Саудовский риял</item>
        <item>Северокорейская вона</item>
        <item>Сейшельская рупия</item>
        <item>Сербский динар</item>
        <item>Сингапурский доллар</item>
        <item>Сирийский фунт</item>
        <item>Сом</item>
        <item>Сомалийский шиллинг</item>
        <item>Сомони</item>
        <item>Суверенный боливар</item>
        <item>Суданский фунт</item>
        <item>Суринамский доллар</item>
        <item>Така</item>
        <item>Тала</item>
        <item>Танзанийский шиллинг</item>
        <item>Тенге</item>
        <item>Тугрик</item>
        <item>Тунисский динар</item>
        <item>Турецкая лира</item>
        <item>Угандийский шиллинг</item>
        <item>Угия</item>
        <item>Узбекский сум</item>
        <item>Уругвайское песо</item>
        <item>Филиппинское песо</item>
        <item>Форинт</item>
        <item>Франк Джибути</item>
        <item>Франк КФА BCEAO</item>
        <item>Франк КФА BEAC</item>
        <item>Франк КФП</item>
        <item>Франк Комор</item>
        <item>Франк Руанды</item>
        <item>Фунт Святой Елены</item>
        <item>Фунт Фолклендских островов</item>
        <item>Фунт стерлингов</item>
        <item>Хорватская куна</item>
        <item>Чешская крона</item>
        <item>Чилийское песо</item>
        <item>Шведская крона</item>
        <item>Швейцарский франк</item>
        <item>Шри-Ланкийская рупия</item>
        <item>Эскудо Кабо-Верде</item>
        <item>Эфиопский быр</item>
        <item>Юань</item>
        <item>Южнокорейская вона</item>
        <item>Южносуданский фунт</item>
        <item>Ямайский доллар</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="currency_codes">
        <item>AUD</item>
        <item>AZN</item>
        <item>DZD</item>
        <item>ARS</item>
        <item>AMD</item>
        <item>AWG</item>
        <item>AFN</item>
        <item>BSD</item>
        <item>PAB</item>
        <item>BBD</item>
        <item>THB</item>
        <item>BHD</item>
        <item>BZD</item>
        <item>BYN</item>
        <item>BMD</item>
        <item>BGN</item>
        <item>BOB</item>
        <item>BRL</item>
        <item>BND</item>
        <item>BIF</item>
        <item>VUV</item>
        <item>XCD</item>
        <item>GYD</item>
        <item>GHS</item>
        <item>GNF</item>
        <item>GIP</item>
        <item>HKD</item>
        <item>UAH</item>
        <item>PYG</item>
        <item>HTG</item>
        <item>GMD</item>
        <item>DKK</item>
        <item>MKD</item>
        <item>AED</item>
        <item>STN</item>
        <item>ZWL</item>
        <item>NAD</item>
        <item>KYD</item>
        <item>USD</item>
        <item>SBD</item>
        <item>TTD</item>
        <item>FJD</item>
        <item>DOP</item>
        <item>VND</item>
        <item>EUR</item>
        <item>EGP</item>
        <item>ZMW</item>
        <item>PLN</item>
        <item>NIO</item>
        <item>JPY</item>
        <item>INR</item>
        <item>JOD</item>
        <item>IQD</item>
        <item>IRR</item>
        <item>ISK</item>
        <item>YER</item>
        <item>CAD</item>
        <item>QAR</item>
        <item>AOA</item>
        <item>MWK</item>
        <item>KES</item>
        <item>GTQ</item>
        <item>PGK</item>
        <item>LAK</item>
        <item>COP</item>
        <item>BAM</item>
        <item>CDF</item>
        <item>CRC</item>
        <item>CUP</item>
        <item>KWD</item>
        <item>MMK</item>
        <item>GEL</item>
        <item>ALL</item>
        <item>HNL</item>
        <item>SLL</item>
        <item>LRD</item>
        <item>LBP</item>
        <item>LYD</item>
        <item>SZL</item>
        <item>LSL</item>
        <item>MUR</item>
        <item>MGA</item>
        <item>MYR</item>
        <item>MAD</item>
        <item>MXN</item>
        <item>MZN</item>
        <item>MDL</item>
        <item>NGN</item>
        <item>ERN</item>
        <item>BTN</item>
        <item>NPR</item>
        <item>ANG</item>
        <item>NZD</item>
        <item>ILS</item>
        <item>PEN</item>
        <item>TWD</item>
        <item>TMT</item>
        <item>NOK</item>
        <item>OMR</item>
        <item>TOP</item>
        <item>PKR</item>
        <item>MOP</item>
        <item>BWP</item>
        <item>KHR</item>
        <item>RUB</item>
        <item>RON</item>
        <item>IDR</item>
        <item>MVR</item>
        <item>ZAR</item>
        <item>SVC</item>
        <item>SAR</item>
        <item>KPW</item>
        <item>SCR</item>
        <item>RSD</item>
        <item>SGD</item>
        <item>SYP</item>
        <item>KGS</item>
        <item>SOS</item>
        <item>TJS</item>
        <item>VES</item>
        <item>SDG</item>
        <item>SRD</item>
        <item>BDT</item>
        <item>WST</item>
        <item>TZS</item>
        <item>KZT</item>
        <item>MNT</item>
        <item>TND</item>
        <item>TRY</item>
        <item>UGX</item>
        <item>MRU</item>
        <item>UZS</item>
        <item>UYU</item>
        <item>PHP</item>
        <item>HUF</item>
        <item>DJF</item>
        <item>XOF</item>
        <item>XAF</item>
        <item>XPF</item>
        <item>KMF</item>
        <item>RWF</item>
        <item>SHP</item>
        <item>FKP</item>
        <item>GBP</item>
        <item>HRK</item>
        <item>CZK</item>
        <item>CLP</item>
        <item>SEK</item>
        <item>CHF</item>
        <item>LKR</item>
        <item>CVE</item>
        <item>ETB</item>
        <item>CNY</item>
        <item>KRW</item>
        <item>SSP</item>
        <item>JMD</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: Покажите `array/currency_names` и `array/currency_codes`

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Эмм... и где же здесь в `currency_codes` 105?  Надо ставить `defaultValue="RUB"`...

Comment: Так тоже пробовал, не получилось

Comment: Разобрался вроде. Какой-то глюк был.. Очистил кэш приложения заработало.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Два варианта:

1) Указывать в `android:defaultValue="RUB"`

2) Чуть хитрее (удобнее с точки зрения локализации):

```
<string name="default>RUB</string>

<ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="@string/default"
        android:entries="@array/currency_names"
        android:entryValues="@array/currency_codes"
        android:key="main_currency"
        android:summary="Выберите основную валюту"
        android:title="Основная валюта" />
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую второй вариант тоже.

Comment: Я извиняюсь.. Можно ли сделать чтобы в summary отображалась выбранная валюта? Чтобы при открытии настроек пользователь видел какая сейчас выбрана валюта по умолчанию.